# Unable to apply filter on a custom lookup field, on the click of another custom lookup field

Tags: lightning-web-components

Project and Unit in  a Master-detail relationship
Project-Master object
Unit - detail object
Price - another custom object
Price contains two custom lookup fields Project, Unit
I have created a custom input form for 'Price' object using lightning web components.
I had defined the fields Project, Unit as:

```
<template>
 <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Price__c">
  <lightning-input-field field-name="Project__c" onchange={projectChange}>
  </lightning-input-field>
  
     <lightning-input-field field-name="Unit__c" value ={unitVal}>
     </lightning-input-field>
  </lightning-record-edit-form>
</template>
```

But when I did so, all projects got listed out in 'Project' field, but 'Unit' field is empty
And also the filter is not working, I need to filter the values of 'Unit' that comes under the selected project.

**JS**

```
    projectChange(event) {

       this.projSelected = event.detail.value[0];

       getUnit({ projId:this.projSelected })

       .then(result => {

        this.unitVal = result;
          })

       .catch(error => {
        this.unitVal = undefined;

       });
```

**Apex class**

```
  @AuraEnabled(cacheable = true)
    public static List<Unit__c> getUnit(Id projId) {
      
        return [SELECT Id,  Name FROM Unit__c where Project__c = :projId ];
    }
```

Is there any mistake in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<lightning-input-field field-name="Unit__c" value ={unitVal}>
</lightning-input-field>
```

In your code, you have used the unit records list for the "value" attribute, but lightning-input-field will not admit that. You can only provide the Id of any unit record to the "value" attribute.

Besides, you can show the unit records in a custom picklist and get the Id of the selected unit record and provide it to the "Unit__c" field of the project at the time of submit of the project record.

Comment: Hi Avi, is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Either you can go for a custom picklist to show Unit records or go with the custom LookUp component.

Comment: Is it possible using a lightning:combobox?

Comment: Yes, that is good.